# `clone()` not working in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I was trying to clone an element and append it to another child with following statement of jQuery:

```
$(userListJId).clone().appendTo(tempOwnJString);
```

Where `userListJId` and `tempOwnJString` are the id's of elements.

The above line of code works fine in Internet Explorer 7 and higher versions of it but does not seem to be working in Internet Explorer 6.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: The definite reason is that IE6 is the worst browser ever invented.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the ID of the cloned object after it's appended?

Comment: @Kolink I'd like to introduce you to Netscape 4. Or, my dear friend HotJava.

Comment: What version of jQuery are we talking about here?

Comment: Didn't jQuery drop IE6 support?

Comment: @Raynos No, they still support IE6.

Comment: IE6, a web developers worst nightmare come true.

Comment: You are missing an important detail:. The Version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: clone is working fine in IE, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cpwYD/1/  . I think you have some problem width the innerHTML. Can you paste the html ?

Comment: @epascarello wouldn't be surprised if he says "jQuery 1.3.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used clone() on IE6 and so that should not be the problem.
Maybe you are creatong invalid HTML and IE6 which is less permissive than IE7 complains about this.
Can you show us your code and also the version of jQuery?

Comment: I m using Jquery version 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

It's funny you should ask this because I had a quite similar problem (though it affected IE7 and probably IE6).

Also, not sure if you have done something special (i.e. defining variables) but perhaps you should refer to the objects as $('#userListJId') instead of just the element name. Again, I can't see the rest of the code, so you may have already defined those variables outside the document.* scope.

Basically, in IE, certain attributes cannot be modified after the object is created, an example being the ID attribute.

The work around is to not clone the object, at least through .clone(), but to take the outer HTML of the object you wish to clone as a string and do a regex .replace() on the id attribute, and then append the modified HTML into tempOwnJString.

Another gotchya in IE, is that sometimes (usually?) when it parses the HTML, it doesn't wrap quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters, so be mindful of this in your regex pattern.

Here is an example of some code I used.

```
    if ($.browser.msie === true)
        {
//unfortunately jQuery doesn't have an outerHTML function, so this is a hacky work around
                templateHTML =  $("#activityTemplate").clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();

                newHTML = templateHTML.replace(/id\=\w+/ig, 'id='+jsonObj.ContactLogID); 
                $(newHTML).prependTo($("#activityContainer"));
// in case i need to refer to newly created object      
                clone = $("#"+jsonObj.ContactLogID); 
        }
```

Again I can't say for certain if this is the issue you're having but with the information you gave and without any debug info (which IE6 doesn't really provide anyway) this is the best guess.

Comment: I see now why @FoxTrot included the regex for setting the ID. Check my answer's comments for a jsfiddle showing this to be unnecessary - IE6 handles ID changes by a normal property setter just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing what @Foxtrot said, you need to ensure you set the id on the cloned element or you'll freak IE6 out. Afterall, all browsers follow the standard that ids must be unique. Their behavior when you violate this varies. You are experiencing variation.

As a trivial example:

```
var clone = $(userListIJD).clone();
clone[0].id = 'somethingElse'; // use a formula here, as presumably this is run over and over
// proceed with appending the clone
```

Comment: True, but like I said, at least in my experience, IE7, and thus, probably IE6, doesn't allow you to alter the id attribute once its set, therefore you have to do the hacky-regex-replace on the HTML string before it's prepended/appended into the DOM.

IE is very fickle with DOM and it gets worse as you go back in history to earlier versions.

Comment: That's incorrect. Start up IE6 and try this jsfiddle with it. http://jsfiddle.net/yHjvz/ The node is duplicated, the ID is set, and the node is appended. IE6 handles it all just fine.

Comment: Perhaps my situation was an IE7 problem. All I know was my cloning mechanism failed on IE7 and when I inserted debug alert()s in it, I noticed the id of the cloned objects. using attr('id', [newid]) weren't changing. As soon as I used my above regex workaround, it rendered just fine. 

I see in your JSfiddle you don't use jQuery but modify the object directly. That could have also been my issue. Either way, it worked for me to do what I did and my original interpretation of Wasim's question suggested his issue was similar to mine, so I shared the workaround code.

Comment: @FoxTrot You're probably running into the old prop()/attr() trouble of jquery. I stick to [0].id whenever dealing with a single tag. It's faster, the code is short, and it works everywhere (IE7 as well), no matter what changes in the jquery API over time.

Comment: I'm using the most up to date version of jQuery, but your advice is something I'll definitely use moving forward. Thank you.